# Are there any benefits from using a @staticmethod?

Tags: python

I was wondering if you use @staticmethod decorator in your code.

Personally I don't use it, since it takes more letters to write @staticmethod then self.

The only benefit (which comes to me) from using it may be a better clarity of a code, but since I usually write a method description for sphinx, I always state whether a method is using object or not.

Or maybe I should start using @staticmethod decorator ?

Comment: Actually, I am still confused: Is there some places that we have to use staticmethod in python3? I find many places is not neccessy to use staticmethod.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Whether to use `@staticmethod` or not depends on what you want to achieve.  Ignoring the decorator because there is more to type is a rather silly reason (no offense!) and indicates that you have not understood the concept of a *static method* in Python!

Static methods are independent of the class and any class instance.  They only use the class scope as a namespace.  If you omit the `@staticmethod` decorator, you are creating an instance method that cannot be used without constructing an instance.

Here is a very simple class `Foo`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...    @staticmethod
...    def foo():
...       print 'foo'
...
...    def bar(self):
...       print 'bar'
```

Now, `Foo.foo()` is a static method that can be called directly:

```
>>> Foo.foo()
foo
```

`Foo.bar()` on the other hand is an *instance method*, that can only be called from instances (objects) of `Foo`:

```
>>> Foo.bar()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unbound method foo() must be called with Foo instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo.bar()
bar
```

To answer your question: If you want to define a static method, use `@staticmethod`.  Otherwise, don't.

If you have a method that does not use `self`, and therefore *could* be written as a static method, ask yourself: Will you ever want to access this function from outside without having an instance?  Most of the times, the answer will be: No.

Comment: +1: "Ignoring the decorator because there is more to type is a rather silly reason".  Drop the apology.  It's silly.

Comment: Just to add one other reason for using staticmethod instead of self - it's not just for python, but for future maintainers as well. It highlights "this function does not depend on the state of the class OR an instance", as opposed to classmethod or an undecorated method. For an maintainer unfamiliar with the code (eg: you, 5 years from now) this makes learning the codebase much faster.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, now when I look at that it's really a silly reason :) I have still a lot to learn, but thanks to you guys learning is not as painful as it used to be.

Comment: then why not just write a solo function out of this class.....

Answer (score 1):

Assume that we want to define `abs` method in class `Math`, then we have two choices:

```
class Math():
    def abs(n):
        if n>0:
            return n
        else:
            return -n

class Math2():
    @staticmethod
    def abs(n):
        if n>0:
            return n
        else:
            return -n
```

**In Python2:**

```
>>> Math.abs(-2)
TypeError: unbound method abs() must be called with Math instance as 
first argument (got int instance instead)

>>>Math().abs(-2)
TypeError: abs() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

>>> Math2.abs(-2)
2

>>> Math2().abs(-2)
2
```

python2 automatically takes `Math().abs(-2)` as `Math().abs(self,-2)`,so that you have to use `@staticmethod`.

**In Python3**

```
>>>Math.abs(-3)
3

>>>Math().abs(-3)
TypeError: abs() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

>>>Math2.abs(-3)
3

>>>Math2().abs(-3)
3
```

In python3, you can use `classname.method()` without static method, but it will raise TypeError when someone tries to use `instance.method()`.

Comment: this different between python2 and python3 make me confused a lot.

Answer (score 0):

`@staticmethod` decorator saves you typing and improves readability.

```
class Example:
    @staticmethod
    def some_method():
        return
```

is the same as:

```
class Example:
    def some_method():
        return
    some_method = staticmethod(some_method)
```

I think you may be confused about what a static method is in Python as the terminology differs from other languages. A regular method is "bound" to the instance (`self`), a class method is "bound" to the class (`cls`) while a static method is not "bound" at all (and can not access instance nor class attributes.

See:

- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod
- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#staticmethod

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous answers,
from pythons doc @staticmethod :

> It can be called either on the class (such as C.f()) or on an instance (such as C().f()). The instance is ignored except for its class.

```
class Test:

@staticmethod
def Foo():
    print('static Foo')

def Bar():
    print('static Bar')


Test.foo() # static Foo
Test.bar() # static Bar

obj = Test()
obj.foo() # static Foo ; note that you can call it from class instance 
obj.bar() # ERROR
```